# How to embed Sqlite in Xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I have a problem embedding a `.db` SQLite file as an embedded resource in my project; I can't find it.

I've set it to always build and that its embedded. I've also tried to add it to the `<Appname>.Android` project as well as the shared project. Ive been stuck on this for some evenings now already so any help is more than welcome.

What I find strange is that I have an `appsettings.json` file and it's found without problems

Here is one of the ways ive tried which is more of a last attempt. previously ive tried

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "file.db"

Path.GetFullPath("App.file.db")

Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("app.file.db"))
```

and many more, and combinations etc

```js
                var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "dbfilename.db");

                if (!File.Exists(path)) throw new Exception("Databasefile not found");

                using (var con = new SqliteConnection($"DataSource = {path}"))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    var dbName = con.Database;
                    var dbPAth = con.DataSource;
                    
                    var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM Table; ";
                    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                    while (reader.Read())
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code.  How are you trying to "find" the db?

Comment: I've edited the post with some sample code

Comment: You are treating an embedded resource like a file, which it is not.    Further, any thing included in the app bundle is read only, you if you need to write to the db it needs to be copied to a writable location.

Comment: Aha, thanks a lot. No wonder i wasnt making any progess